# Porque VBA retorna erro de #valor

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, visual-basic-6, microsoft-office

Olá tenho o seguinte código vba que é uma função que recebe três parâmetros e calcula as funções bult-in  tendência e rquad e a depender do resultado ela retorna tendência ou a média dos ultimos valores.

```
Function CAPACIDADEPORT(KY As Range, KX As Range, UX)

    Dim RQUAD As Double
    Dim TENDE As Variant
    
    RQUAD = Application.WorksheetFunction.RSq(KY.Value, KX.Value)
    TENDE = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trend(KY.Value, KX.Value, UX.Value)
    
    If RQUAD > 0.6 Then
        CAPACIDADEPORT = TENDE
        
    Else:
        CAPACIDADEPORT = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(KY.Cells(KY.Cells.Count).Offset(-4).Resize(5))
    End If
        
End Function
```

Essa função acima funciona normalmente. O problema é quando eu adiciono mais um teste no if(TENDE > 0), após eu mudar ela sempre retorna erro de valor sendo que os dados que eu passo como parametro para as duas são os mesmos.

```
Function CAPACIDADEPORT(KY As Range, KX As Range, UX)
    
        Dim RQUAD As Double
        Dim TENDE As Variant
        
        RQUAD = Application.WorksheetFunction.RSq(KY.Value, KX.Value)
        TENDE = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trend(KY.Value, KX.Value, UX.Value)
        
        If RQUAD > 0.6 AND TENDE > 0 Then
            CAPACIDADEPORT = TENDE
            
        Else:
            CAPACIDADEPORT = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(KY.Cells(KY.Cells.Count).Offset(-4).Resize(5))
        End If
            
    End Function
```

Gostaria de saber o que pode estar levando a esse erro.
Grato desde já.

Comment: Como você esta chamando a função na planilha, está incluindo os 3 argumentos? Notei que o último parâmetro você não marcou como `As Range`, o que está indo pra ele?

Comment: No ultimo parametro vai somente uma célula com um número. Chamao a função dessa forma: =capacidadeport(B2:B15;A2:A15;A16)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.trend) da função deixa a desejar ao informar que retorna um `Variant` quando na verdade ela retorna um `Array de Variant`. Você pode verificar isso usando o [VarType](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function).

Nos meus testes, mesmo quando passava UX com apenas uma célula ele retornava um `Array` com 2 valores, sendo o segundo valor a tendência propriamente dita (não tenho certeza do que veio no primeiro elemento). Adicionando (1) na frente do cálculo de `TENDE` corrigiu o comportamento.

Segue o código corrigido:

```
Function CAPACIDADEPORT(KY As Range, KX As Range, UX As Range)
    
    Dim RQUAD As Double
    Dim TENDE As Variant
    
    RQUAD = Application.WorksheetFunction.RSq(KY, KX)
    TENDE = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trend(KY, KX, UX)(1)
    
    If RQUAD > 0.6 And TENDE > 0 Then
        CAPACIDADEPORT = TENDE
        
    Else:
        CAPACIDADEPORT = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(KY.Cells(KY.Cells.Count).Offset(-4).Resize(5))
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Muito obrigado. Ajudou muito, realmente a documentação da função deixa a desejar e  acho estranho retornar uma array, mas enfim, fica a dica para eu prestar mais atenção.